# Why is the word "bought" incorrect in "Did you change your mind and bought the red car?"

Tags: verbs, past-tense, questions, do-support

> Did you change your mind and bought the red car?

Why is the word "bought" incorrect in this context? I was teaching ESL and this question came up.

Comment: Would you say, “Did you *bought* the car” or “Did you ***buy*** the car?”

Comment: Break it into two simple sentences.  "Did you change your mind?" and "Did you bought the red car?"  Do you see anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the conjunction(and) and break the sentence into two clauses. It will be

> Did you change your mind?

And

> Did you **buy** the red car?

As you can see, **did** is the helping verb for both verbs: *Change* and *buy*. I'm sure you were told by your English teacher to always use a bare infinitive verb after *did*. It's a basic rule that is commonly taught.

Answer (score -2):

It is incorrect because 'change' is present tense and 'bought' is past tense.
"You changed your mind and bought the red car?" Both verbs past tense.
"Did you change your mind and buy the red car?" Both verbs present tense.

Comment: "Did" is also a verb.

Comment: When dealing with "did change" and "did buy", both "change" and "buy" are infinitive -- they have no tense.